# Javascript - Merge two sorted linked lists understanding

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why in the following function, at certein point they do `mergedTail.next = temp; mergedTail = temp;` Instead of to have only `mergedTail = temp;`:

```
let merge_sorted = function(head1, head2) {
  // if both lists are empty then merged list is also empty
  // if one of the lists is empty then other is the merged list
  if (!head1) {
      return head2;
  } else if (!head2) {
      return head1;
  }

  let mergedHead = null;
  if (head1.data <= head2.data) {
      mergedHead = head1;
      head1 = head1.next;
  } else {
      mergedHead = head2;
      head2 = head2.next;
  }

  let mergedTail = mergedHead;

  while (head1 && head2) {    
      let temp = null;
      if (head1.data <= head2.data) {
          temp = head1;
          head1 = head1.next;
      } else {
          temp = head2;
          head2 = head2.next;
      }

    mergedTail.next = temp;
    mergedTail = temp;
  }

  if (head1) {
      mergedTail.next = head1;
  } else if (head2) {
      mergedTail.next = head2;
  }

  return mergedHead;
};
```

Many thanks.

Comment: It would help if you clicked edit then `[<>]` snippet editor and added a working [mcve]

Comment: The best way to understand this algorithm is to use pen and paper. Draw a rectangle for each node and an arrow for a link. Start with two sorted lists containing two elements elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mergedTail` always refers to the last element of the merged list. `temp` is set to the element that should be appended to that list next.

By setting `mergedTail.next = temp`, the element `temp` is appended to the merged list. But now `mergedTail` no longer refers to the last element, but to the second-to-last element. So we assign `mergedTail = temp` to move it one step ahead, and maintain our invariant.

I would personally have preferred `mergedTail = mergedTail.next`, which is equivalent and maybe slightly less efficient, but makes the intent clearer.

Comment: No sorry, getting again confused. My question was, once you do ```mergedTail = temp``` you are overriding the entire mergedTail obj, so even ```mergedTail.next```. This is what I cannot understand.

Comment: You're not overwriting the entire object, only the reference to that object. Yes, there's no longer an easy way to access the element that `mergedTail` originally referred to, but you don't need it anymore; you only need the `mergedHead` to eventually return it from the function.